# Can I connect via OBDC to database in IBM Data Studio?

Tags: ibm-data-studio

Is there a way to connect to my IBM AS/400 Database using ODBC in IBM Data Studio? It seems as though IBM Data studio is limited to JDBC connections which is not compatible with our server.

I tried to conenct to our database using the JDBC AS/400 toolbox option and the connection failed. I know we use ODBC so i think that's what it is.